# Recognize the type of Alexa device from the JSON request

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I want to determine whether the device using my Alexa skill has a screen or not so that I can provide the correct responses and include Cards, or Images, etc.

I have looked through the **[Request and Response JSON Reference](https://developer.amazon.com/de/docs/custom-skills/request-and-response-json-reference.html)** and expected to find something in Context or System object that would set the devices apart.

From the docs and my own test logs, `event.context.System.device.supportedInterfaces` appears to either be an empty array, or include an `AudioPlayer` array. Is there nothing there for visual interfaces?

Another option I thought to look for is a difference in the `event.context. Viewport` array. Is there a way to know which device is being used by comparing the dimensions and shape?

**[Viewport Reference](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/alexa-presentation-language/apl-viewport-property.html)** and example:

```
[Viewport] => Array (
            [experiences] => Array (
                   [0] => Array (
                         [arcMinuteWidth] => 144
                         [arcMinuteHeight] => 144
                         [canRotate] => 
                         [canResize] => 
                   )

             )

             [shape] => ROUND
             [pixelWidth] => 480
             [pixelHeight] => 480
             [dpi] => 160
             [currentPixelWidth] => 480
             [currentPixelHeight] => 480
             [touch] => Array (
                   [0] => SINGLE
             )
             [keyboard] => Array ()
)
```

But I cannot find the properties of the possible devices to match to the Viewport dimensions.

So does anyone have a solution to recognizing the Alexa device being used, specifically to know whether the device has a built-in screen or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After testing the devices that I have available, I found that the `Viewport` array is **only** supplied when the device has a screen. No need to compare `Viewport` elements.

So to determine if the incoming Alexa request has an attached screen I simply do:

```
if (event.context.Viewport) {
    // device has a screen
}
```

**NOTE: Sending cards to any device (screen or not) will also be visible in the Alexa App.** So after detecting a screen, I am sending a card to be displayed on every turn. And if detecting no screen, then I am only sending the occasional card for the user to check their Alexa App to view the card there. So I was surprised to see all of the cards viewed on the screen, also flooded the app.

Comment: Is Amazon still sending it? I don;t see the Viewport data neither from Show or Spot...

Comment: @BelaVizy That's true, not too long after this, I too stopped receiving Viewport data. I have not heard or seen any official update from Amazon yet either....but it does seem to be a change they recently put in place affecting many if not all of us devs.

Comment: @BelaVizy I just saw another user report that it came back, and so I just double checked too. I **do** see it again where it should be `event.context.Viewport`. Amazon must have made a mistake somewhere and just fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

*For others who are here to try and get visuals working in their Alexa skill.*

To have the `"Alexa.Presentation.APL"` appear in your `supportedInterfaces` array, you need to enable it in the Alexa Developer Console for that skill. You have to enable `Alexa Presentation Language` under the `Interfaces` tab. [Reference](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/alexa-presentation-language/use-apl-with-ask-sdk.html#make-sure-the-users-device-supports-apl)

If this is enabled and `supportedInterfaces` is still empty (from a device with a screen/APL support), ensure that no other skill exists with the same invocation phrase (name it something ridiculously unique to test), and then retry.